# Convert JSON Result to list<>

Tags: c#, asp.net

**ERROR**

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RechargePortal.Models.ProviderOperator]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'providers', line 1, position
>   13.'

```
List<ProviderOperator> GetProvideOperator(string service)
{
    string json = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("URL");
    List<ProviderOperator> ob = new List<ProviderOperator>();
    ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProviderOperator>>(json);
    ob = ob.Where(x => x.Service.Equals(service)).ToList();
    return ob;
}
```

**JSON RESULT**

```
{
   "providers":[
      {
         "provider_id":0,
         "provider_name":"PAY2ALL",
         "provider_code":"PAY2ALL",
         "service_id":10,
         "service":"Pay2All Cash",
         "provider_image":"",
         "status":"Success"
      },
      {
         "provider_id":1,
         "provider_name":"AIRTEL",
         "provider_code":"A",
         "service_id":1,
         "service":"Recharge",
         "provider_image":"provider_icons\/airtel.png",
         "status":"Success"
      },
      {
         "provider_id":2,
         "provider_name":"VODAFONE",
         "provider_code":"V",
         "service_id":1,
         "service":"Recharge",
         "provider_image":"provider_icons\/vodafone.png",
         "status":"Success"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Model**

```
public class ProviderOperator 
{ 
    public string Provider_id { get; set; } 
    public string Provider_name { get; set; } 
    public string Provider_code { get; set; } 
    public string Service { get; set; } 
    public string Provider_image { get; set; } 
    public string Status { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: your json isn't a list, it's an object with a list in it

Comment: You may use some online tools to ensure that you get your JSON into C# correctly: http://json2csharp.com

Comment: Very nice website :) - @AbdullahDibas

Answer (score 4):

You should try following class:

```
public class ProviderOperator
{
    public List<Provider> providers { get; set; }
}

public class Provider
{
    public int provider_id { get; set; }
    public string provider_name { get; set; }
    public string provider_code { get; set; }
    public int service_id { get; set; }
    public string service { get; set; }
    public string provider_image { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

var ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProviderOperator>(json);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Json Result is in different format and the class structure you are using
to parse json is in different format.
You need to create two separate classes as follows

### Class Structure

```
 public class ProviderOperator
  {
        public List<ProviderInfo> providers { get; set; }
  }
 public class ProviderInfo
  {
        public int provider_id { get; set; }
        public string provider_name { get; set; }
        public string provider_code { get; set; }
        public int service_id { get; set; }
        public string service { get; set; }
        public string provider_image { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
   }
```

### Parsing Response

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProvderOperator>(json);
```